# Apisix Target Down in Prometheus(Kube-Prometheus-Stack)

Tags: prometheus, metrics, apache-apisix

I installed Apisix (using the helm chart) as my api-gateway on my EKS cluster and configured the prometheus plugin as shown in the apisix documentation >> https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/3.2/plugins/prometheus/.
However, prometheus is showing my apisix target is down.

I configured the apisix servicemonitor and added prometheus plugin to the configmap - config.yaml as below (gateway is the namespace I installed apisix). I am able to see the get the metrics using local host from the apisix-gateway service but not from prometheus as the target is down.  I also changed the plugin export ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 but it didnt resolve it.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: apisix-metrics
  labels:
    app: apisix
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - gateway
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      helm.sh/chart: apisix-2.1.0
      app.kubernetes.io/name: apisix
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: apisix
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "3.4.0"
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/service: apisix-gateway
  endpoints:
    - scheme: http
      targetPort: prometheus
      path: /apisix/prometheus/metrics
      interval: 15s
---

plugins:
  - prometheus
plugin_attr:
  prometheus:
    export_uri: /apisix/prometheus/metrics
    metrics: apisix_
    enable_export_server: true
    export_addr:
      ip: 0.0.0.0
      port: 9091
```

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
containers:
- name: apisix
  ports:
    - name: prometheus
      containerPort: 9091
      protocol: TCP
```

add this to apisix deployment work for me!